# Do we have a such idiom, "right at hand" ? What does it mean?

Tags: idioms

> Crying is **right at hand** in the smoothering dark, closed inside someone else, when you see how everything you can ever accomplish will end up as trash.

Source: Fight Club by Chuck Palahniuk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

> right at hand

is a phrase that may literally imply that some implement is within touching distance, or may be used more metaphorically to indicate that some desired information or assistance is readily available. Here the usage indicates that one may readily start crying.

I might instead say

> I have xxx close to hand

or even

> I have xxx to hand

Comment: I disagree with "close to hand" being an equivalent. _Near my hand_ – sure, but not "I have xxx close to hand."

Comment: @J.R. -  I think "close to hand" is fine.  [Google Books provides many examples.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22close+to+hand%22)    You think "near my hand" is better?  It doesn't have the same idiomatic meaning, to my thinking.

Comment: @stangdon - Interesting. The expression doesn't sound familiar to me – maybe it's a regional thing? The [BrEng ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right+at+hand%2Cclose+to+hand&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3) and the [AmEng ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right+at+hand%2Cclose+to+hand&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3) suggest it might be. Anyhow, thanks for correcting me and setting the record straight.

Comment: Yes, I am British, "close to hand" was the phrase I would use, I was surprised to find "right at hand" was valid.